# Java error with kodak app

Tags: macos, java, jre

I've run out of options with the kodak development guys, so I am hoping that someone here will have an answer.  We runs kodak asset management system and some machines, get this error when trying to launch the included java app.  The machines are macs, running 10.9.1 with JRE v7b51.  Not all machines running this setup have this problem.  I have reinstalled Java, emptied all caches, tried install older builds of JRE.  All to no avail.  We can't really change the code of the app, but since it works on some machines, I believe it must be linked to a bad pref file or some other anomaly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.mrj.MRJFileUtils

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.creo.insite.submitit.client.ui.mac.FolderSelectorMRJ.getUserPrefsFolder(FolderSelectorMRJ.java:237)
at com.creo.insite.submitit.client.ui.mac.FolderSelectorMRJ.getUserAppDataDirectory(FolderSelectorMRJ.java:224)
at com.creo.shared.util.applet.BrowserEnv.getMRJInsiteDir(BrowserEnv.java:740)
at com.creo.shared.util.applet.BrowserEnv.getInsitePersistPath(BrowserEnv.java:712)
at com.kodak.insite.SmartReview.Manager.ClientPreferencesManager.<clinit>(ClientPreferencesManager.java:43)
at com.kodak.insite.SmartReview.SmartReviewApplet.main(SmartReviewApplet.java:2023)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: We'll need some more information: What software exactly is this (can you give a link)? Is the problem reproducible, or intermittent? It it is reproducible, how exactly? Is the error message always the same?

Comment: Compare the CLASSPATH variable on a working machine to the non-working ones.  Compare the Java Extensions libraries between the two machines to look for missing/different .JAR and .class files.

Comment: The error message is always the same.  It is consistently reproducible on the machines that have the error. Though I have machines on the same version of OSX with the same setup with the same JRE that don't have the error.  The software is called SmartReview it's written by Kodak.  I can't give a link without an account.  if someone is really interested message me privately and I can setup an account for them.

Comment: how do I find out the current class path on an app that comes to me compiled.  From what I just read, it seems like there would be a terminal command?